# In Clion's debugger, how do I show the entire contents of an int array

Tags: c++, c, debugging, gdb, clion

Right now it is only showing the first element of the array but I want a visual of all the elements in the array. I think Clion is using GDB.

EDIT: I am referring specifically to arrays on the heap. Arrays on the stack can be visualised.

Comment: There's no such feature in CLion right now, unfortunately. Here's the corresponding feature request though: [CPP-6550 'Show as array' for pointer variables](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-6550), please upvote if that's the case for you.

Comment: FTR: You vote up by clicking the *tiny* thumb-up icon on the right side of the page.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Unfortunately, CLion doesn't currently support such feature. As suggested [by JetBrains employee](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-6550), you can use a workaround. In Evaluate / Watches window use the following expression:

```
(MyType[128])myArray
```

You can use arbitrary array size; whatever works for you.

If you array is stored in `void *` variable, you need to do something more tricky:

```
(MyType[128])*(char*)myArray
```

Comment: Note (MyType[128])myArray works for LLDB. For GDB, use (MyType[128])*myArray to have correct results.

Comment: @cubuspl42, thank you for your solution. `void *` works for any type

Comment: `(char *[10])*argv` If you are trying to watch the program's command line arguments. `argv` itself is null terminated. You will see environment variables after the null, or maybe garbage on non unixy systems.

Comment: This unfortunately didn't work for in Linux with CLion, with/out asterisk; I think you might have to do a few CMAKE flags first or at least built with optimisation.

Answer (score 68):

The answer by [cubuspl42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1483676/cubuspl42) works for GDB. But if you're on a Mac using LLDB as your debugger, the correct method is

```
(MyType(*)[128])myArray
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: save me a night

Comment: Any LLDB doc about this?

Answer (score 6):

Any syntax understood by the underlying debugger should work, actually. In the case of GDB, for example, you could use `*array@size`, where `array` can be any pointer expression and `size` can be any (positive) integer expression, and both can include variables, function calls, registers, anything that GDB understands. Something like this would be valid, for example:

```
*((int*)$rsp - 0x100)@get_size(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem today, but instead, I had an array of pointers;

```
pthread_t** pthreads = (pthread_t**) malloc(//malloc args)
thread_count = 0;

while(thread_count < 10) {
    pthread_t* myThread = (pthread_t*) malloc(//malloc args)
    pthreads[thread_count] = myThread;
    thread_count++;
}
```

I had trouble seeing the allocation of this memory in CLion gdb because it looked at a pointer to a pointer.

I solved this by targetting the first element of my array (pthreads[0]) and then looking at the next `n` elements from there.

To do this you need to cast the type (pthread_t*[]) and then use the target memory, which is pthreads[0] (i.e first element)

Note: I used `calloc` with 0 to set my `pthreads` array. This photo shows how memory was allocated correctly at position 0 in the CLion debugger.

I made this post because none of the posts above led me to the conclusion that I wrote here.

Example: [image: clion gdb feature]

Answer (score 1):

You can use template and reference:

```
template<int N>
void foo1(int (&arr)[N])
{
    ...
}
```

If you want to pass the array to other function, the passed function should also use template and reference for array:

```
template<int N>
void foo2(int (&arr)[N])
{
    ...
}
template<int N>
void foo1(int (&arr)[N])
{
    foo2(arr);
}
```

This method allows you to see the entire contents of an int array in clion

Answer (score 1):

Note that as of version 2021.3, you can now view pointers as arrays by right-clicking on the specific variable in the variable viewer and selecting "View as Array...": https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/examining-suspended-program.html#view-as-array

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).