# How to see actual value of a C++ string in CLion's debugger?

Tags: c++, debugging, clion, watch

I'm using CLion on Linux and having difficulties with debugging. I evaluated an expression which ends up being a string, but the debugger is useless at showing me what the return value is, other than that it is a string. How do I see the actual value? (also note it doesn't even show the value of `char` values)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please check that *Enable GNU C++ Value Renderers* option is on in *Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Debugger*.

Comment: @EldarAbusalimov I have enabled that, but all I got is random hexadecimal value, not the real one.

Comment: @ismailsunni Could you check a workaround suggested in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-6828 (`add_definitions(-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0)`)? Does it help?

Comment: I know old question, but just refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40327089/in-clions-debugger-how-do-i-show-the-entire-contents-of-an-int-array) here.

Answer (score 6):

With gdb you can print std::string by below 2 methods.

1. p mystr.c_str() -this can be used to print value of type std::string.
2. p *(char**) 0x7f8fbb7a9c20 -this works for a memory with type std::string.

Comment: It’s 2020, and this is how we have to print std::string Values in a debugger: `p *(char**) 0x7f8fbb7a9c20`...

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a bug of LLDB. You can check this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-13701

I have tried GDB, and it works well, so you can switch to GDB toolchains to avoid this problem.

---

However, in 2021, if you have to use LLDB, you can use the memory address of the variable `std::string mystr;`

- In LLDB console: `p *(char**) &mystr`
- Or, add this expression `*(char**) &mystr` into the watcher window of CLion-2021 debugger

Answer (score 0):

Just add a watch for a desired `std::string` expression and edit the watch to append `.c_str()` (<kbd>F2</kbd> will work fine for that).

E.g. for examining the `my_cpp_str` variable, add the following watch:

`my_cpp_str.c_str()`